# storing random query result in session to preserve order of result

Tags: php, mysql, session

i want to store result of my query in session and when user refresh the page i want to show him same result stored in session. if session is null then query again and when user leave the page session should be deleted.what i really want to do is

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['result']))
{//if session is null then query database and store result in session
$query="SELECT * from table order by rand()";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$_SESSION['result']=$result;
while ($read_all_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($_SESSION['result']))
{
//echo data
}
else //if there is result in session then dont query just show me data
{
while ($read_all_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($_SESSION['result']))
{
echo //same data
}
}
```

i am doing some thing wrong. i am selecting random rows from database.i want to preserve that order. you will not get new rows from pressing refresh button

Comment: What problem / error are you facing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting random rows from database only for one time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024117/selecting-random-rows-from-database-only-for-one-time)

Comment: You have already asked this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024117/selecting-random-rows-from-database-only-for-one-time

Comment: both are different questions sir. first question is related to database query (if there is any query that allows user to select random data for one time)
this time i want to store result in session.
if($_session is null then query esle show me same data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing a `mysqli_result` object, and there is no way to serialize it. You cannot serialize external resources in general.

Just put all the data in an array, and store it in its place.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['result'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * from table order by rand()";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $all = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $all[] = $row;
    }

    $_SESSION['result'] = $all;
}

foreach ($_SESSION['result'] as $data) {
    // work with $data
}
```